# Do you use 'invite in~ '?

Tags: meaning, grammar

The following is what Sophia, AI, said in an event last year. Sadly, I am not quite sure what the phrase in boldface means. I have been looking up 'invite in' in a number of dictionaries, which was in vain.

> Sophia : I’m always happy when surrounded by smart people who also
>   happens to be rich and powerful. I was told the people here at the
>   Future Investment Initiative are interested in **inviting in future
>   initiatives**, which means AI, which means me, so I’m more than happy.
>   I’m excited.

Comment: Maybe, she's saying **investing**. Where did you get this quote from? There is also at least one grammatical mistake that I can spot in this passage.

Comment: Yes, 'happens to.' She(Sophia) actually pronounced that way. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMrX08PxUNY

Comment: This is a transcript of spoken English. Transcripts invariably have issues of one type or another. Unless this is to be published as an interview, there is no reason to clean it up. Transcripts are typically also used in court cases and transcriptionists are not always perfect beings....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what she really should have said is *investing*. *Inviting* makes no sense whatsoever in this context while *investing* is a perfect fit. *To invest in an initiative* is a very common phrasing in business circles. This is simply a mistake on her part. There is also another grammatical mistake in this passage that I can spot. There obviously should be no *s* at the end of *happens* because the subject of the *smart people who also happens to be rich and powerful* is a plural noun.

Why does she make such simple grammar and vocabulary blunders when she is speaking English? I would think that it has to do with the fact that she is a robot whose IA module responsible for speech synthesis, while no doubt state of the art, is not without its flaws. That's the only way this can be explained.

Comment: Transcriptions often have mistakes. it's quite common. And can be laid at the feet of the person transcribing the text or the speaker. And speaker's speaking off the cuff are not always perfect grammarians.